# How to use LazyList and takeWhile or dropWhile and avoid producing a never-ending stream?

Tags: scala

My goal is to create an infinite stream of state objects where each successive object modifies itself, and the stream terminates when a certain state is reached. For example, in the sample below, the state object just increments itself, and I want to get the last object before 100.

```
object LazyListTest extends App {
  val test = LazyListTest()
  val last: LazyListTest = test.playout.takeWhile(_.a < 100).last
}

case class LazyListTest(a: Int = 0, maybePrev: Option[LazyListTest] = None) {
  def playout: LazyList[LazyListTest] = this #:: playout.map {
    n => n.increment
  }
  def increment: LazyListTest = {
    copy(a + 1, maybePrev = Some(this))
  }
}
```

In the example above, I expected to get an object back with `a == 99`. Instead, the list never ends. When it hits 99, the stream just repeats starting back at 0. (Which is another question, what is creating this new object?)

When I use `dropWhile`, the stream also repeats infinitely, but it goes beyond 99, repeating at an incremental value above 99 (e.g. 101, 102, ...).

Comment: It probably would be better to use `unfold` for this.

Comment: Seems to work for me. `LazyListTest().playout.takeWhile(_.a < 3).length` returns `3`, and `LazyListTest().playout.takeWhile(_.a < 3).last.a` returns `2`.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Which version of Scala are you using? I'm using 2.13.4.

Comment: @AaronPerrin [Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/M9CtluN7QfWvSPWjYz9CeQ) is 2.13.5. I am pretty sure, version does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's easy to do with `.find(_a == 99)`